# Get the users who are sent themselves of the messages with the last messages and to sort out by created_at

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have a serious problem with the threads that makes some days now. I use Laravel 5.8, during all these times I have make some research everywhere and I read full of the articles but no of the gotten reply could not solve my problem, If he/it pleases you I have bésoin of your helps. I want récupperer all users who sent messages with the connected user and all what were contact by him with the last message by created_at of the messages.
thanks for your helps !!!

This some informations

[migration table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1fs4.png)

[table from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EznAK.png)

[And view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2q3J.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1fs4.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? also don't put up pictures of code, code is text, add it to your question

Comment: It’s not so easy to accomplish the way you set it up. From the top of my head, maybe, if you add a is_last_message_in_thread (bool) it would let you filter it nicely for both users. Otherwise it can become messy.